# How to populate 'select' from database in asp.net using webservice

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, web-services, drop-down-menu

I have a html control select
**HTML**:

```
 <select id="selectGroup" runat="server" name="D1"> 
 </select>
```

How can I populate it with data from my SQL Server database using web-service JavaScript/jQuery/JSON?

Please, do not post answers on how to populate a **asp:DropDownList** because I already know how to do it, I must use a select control. And do not post code behind also I already know how to do it.

I try it from web-service that fetch data is good but it not populate or can't select value. Fetch data from the database and the first column value is only showing.

**WEBSERVICE CODE**:

```
 [WebMethod]
public string GetSelectOptionData() // to show select option in vehiclegroup. //trying

{
    string jsondata = "";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString.ToString());
    SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand("Select VehicleNo from sampleDeviceData", conn);

    SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand);

    DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
    conn.Open();
    da2.Fill(ds2, "sampleDeviceData");
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    da2.Fill(dt);


    jsondata = DataTableToJSONWithJavaScriptSerializer(dt);

    conn.Close();


    return jsondata;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**:

```
  function SelectOptionData() {
var select = document.getElementById("selectGroup");
$("#selectGroup").empty();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "ShowTable.asmx/GetSelectOptionData",
    data: "{}",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        var filedata = [1];
        var elements = Array();
        elements = jQuery.parseJSON(data.d);
        //alert(elements.length);                 // shows length of elements (var elements = Array();)
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            filedata.push({

                ItemName: elements[i]['VehicleNo']

            });
            //alert(filedata.length);             // shows length of filedata (var filedata = [0];)   
            //create the option and append to the dropdown
            var opt = filedata[i + 1].ItemName;
            var el = document.createElement("option");
            el.textContent = opt;
            el.value = opt;
            select.appendChild(el);
        }
    },
    failure: function (data) {
        alert("err in select option");
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(xhr.responseText);
        alert(thrownError);
    }
});}
```

Comment: HTML:<select class="form-control" id="selectGroup" style="height:31px;" runat="server" name="D1">
      </select>

Comment: Since you have `$.ajax()`, you should have access to use `$.each()`, so I think you can simplify to `$(elements).each(function (i, value) { // populate option lists here })`.